# Is there a tool to identify the source of each identifier/type in a C file with respect to the header file it was defined it?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a porting job from one OS to another.  A lot of the work is removing OS-specific header files from the code, and defining the old symbols in a new header, or refactoring the code a bit.  I've been commenting out the `#include "rtos.h"` lines and seeing what symbols become undefined and porting those, but there are many such files and it's tedious and error prone.

Is there a tool or better way to do this?  It would help of each line in the C file would be annotated with the origin of the symbol.

```
if (errno == EIO)                        "EIO" in errno.h
{ ...
}
```

Comment: You could look for the POSIX command (utility) [`cxref`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cxref.html).